# What happens when I can't classify data?

Tags: classification

I have following dataset:

```
a1  a2  dec
2   1   0
0   0   1
4   0   1
8   0   0
4   0   1
4   1   0
6   0   0
2   0   0
4   0   1
4   1   1
```

Based on that, I've created the tree:

[image]

However, when analyzing the attributes, I run into an issue:

We have 2 records, with a1 = 4, a2 = 1, that lead to two different decisions. What should I do with this - is this correct way of structuring the tree, or simply speaking it impossible to build?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean "do with this"?  Are you expecting your tree to perfectly classify all the data?  If so, you have just discovered that is impossible!

Comment: @whuber my bad. I want to know there is any solution to this problem, so that I can indeed build the tree.

Comment: What does solving the problem mean?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly depends on the purpose of the tree. In many cases, the best result may be 0.5 as a result. It appears from the column name, that 'dec' is a decision and 0.5 may not be a suitable answer. Then you might consider giving this combination a random result until more of these constellations (4/1/?) appear in the training data set. The third way might be to check, whether a1=4 or a2=1 is in itself a strong indicator of dec=0 or dec=1, Independent of the other ai. However, there are many degrees of researcher's freedom in the last approach, so most of the time I would favour the first two.